# How to empty all the contents of the table with one click

Tags: jquery

I am using following table. I have a radio button with options 'Yes' and 'No', Yes to show the table and fill the content where as no to hide the table. What I want to do is that when the user selects the option 'No' it should remove all the values using jquery loop. I don't know to use it so please help me out in this.

```
<table id="ownersInfo_2" style="display:none;">
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td colspan="3">
                <table>
                    <tr>
                        <td>First Name:<br>
                            <span class="wpcf7-form-control-wrap sndfnm_cls">
                                <input  id="00N2C000000blNO" maxlength="40" name="00N2C000000blNO" size="20" type="text" />
                                <div class="error-inner">This field is required.</div>
                            </span>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                </table>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td colspan="3">Title:<br>
                <span class="wpcf7-form-control-wrap sndttl_cls">
                    <select  id="00N2C000000blOW" name="00N2C000000blOW" title="Title 2"><option value="">--None--</option><option value="Owner">Owner</option>
                        <option value="Additional Guarantor">Additional Guarantor</option>
                        <option value="Other">Other</option>
                        <option value="Partner">Partner</option>
                        <option value="Managing Member">Managing Member</option>
                        <option value="Member">Member</option>
                        <option value="President">President</option>
                        <option value="CEO">CEO</option>
                        <option value="Vice President">Vice President</option>
                        <option value="Chief Operating Officer">Chief Operating Officer</option>
                        <option value="Chief Financial Officer">Chief Financial Officer</option>
                        <option value="Treasurer">Treasurer</option>
                        <option value="Secretary">Secretary</option>
                    </select>
                    <div class="error-inner">This field is required.</div>
                </span>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td colspan="3">Email:<br>
                <span class="wpcf7-form-control-wrap sndemal_cls">
                    <input  id="00N2C000000blP5" maxlength="80" name="00N2C000000blP5" size="20" type="text" />
                    <div class="error-inner">Please enter a valid email address.</div>
                </span>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>City:<br>
                <span class="wpcf7-form-control-wrap sndcty_cls">
                   <input  id="00N2C000000blPe" maxlength="255" name="00N2C000000blPe" size="20" type="text" />
                    <div class="error-inner">This field is required.</div>
                </span>
            </td>
            <td>State:<br>
                <span class="wpcf7-form-control-wrap sndstat_cls">
                    <select  id="00N2C000000blPy" name="00N2C000000blPy" title="State__c 2"><option value="">--None--</option><option value="Alabama">Alabama</option>
                        <option value="Alaska">Alaska</option>
                        <option value="Arizona">Arizona</option>
                        <option value="Arkansas">Arkansas</option>
                        <option value="California">California</option>
                        <option value="Colorado">Colorado</option>
                        <option value="Connecticut">Connecticut</option>
                        <option value="Delaware">Delaware</option>
                        <option value="District of Columbia">District of Columbia</option>
                        <option value="Florida">Florida</option>
                        <option value="Georgia">Georgia</option>
                        <option value="Hawaii">Hawaii</option>
                        <option value="Idaho">Idaho</option>
                        <option value="Illinois">Illinois</option>
                        <option value="Indiana">Indiana</option>
                        <option value="Iowa">Iowa</option>
                        <option value="Kansas">Kansas</option>
                        <option value="Kentuky">Kentuky</option>
                        <option value="Louisiana">Louisiana</option>
                        <option value="Maine">Maine</option>
                        <option value="Maryland">Maryland</option>
                        <option value="Massachusetts">Massachusetts</option>
                        <option value="Michigan">Michigan</option>
                        <option value="Minnesota">Minnesota</option>
                        <option value="Mississippi">Mississippi</option>
                        <option value="Missouri">Missouri</option>
                        <option value="Montana">Montana</option>
                        <option value="Nebraska">Nebraska</option>
                        <option value="Nevada">Nevada</option>
                        <option value="New Hampshire">New Hampshire</option>
                        <option value="New Jersey">New Jersey</option>
                        <option value="New Mexico">New Mexico</option>
                        <option value="New York">New York</option>
                        <option value="North Carolina">North Carolina</option>
                        <option value="North Dakota">North Dakota</option>
                        <option value="Ohio">Ohio</option>
                        <option value="Oklahoma">Oklahoma</option>
                        <option value="Oregon">Oregon</option>
                        <option value="Pennsylvania">Pennsylvania</option>
                        <option value="Rhode Island">Rhode Island</option>
                        <option value="South Carolina">South Carolina</option>
                        <option value="South Dakota">South Dakota</option>
                        <option value="Tennessee">Tennessee</option>
                        <option value="Texas">Texas</option>
                        <option value="Utah">Utah</option>
                        <option value="Vermont">Vermont</option>
                        <option value="Virginia">Virginia</option>
                        <option value="Washington">Washington</option>
                        <option value="West Virginia">West Virginia</option>
                        <option value="Wisconsin">Wisconsin</option>
                        <option value="Wyoming">Wyoming</option>
                    </select>
                <div class="error-inner">This field is required.</div>
                </span>
            </td>
            <td>Zip:<br>
                <span class="wpcf7-form-control-wrap sndzip_cls">
                    <input  id="00N2C000000blQI" maxlength="5" onkeyup="if (/\D/g.test(this.value)) this.value = this.value.replace(/\D/g,'')" name="00N2C000000blQI" size="20" type="text" />
                    <div class="error-inner">This field is required.</div>
                </span>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td colspan="3">Percentage of Ownership:<br>
                <span class="wpcf7-form-control-wrap sndpercent_cls">
                    <select  id="00N2C000000blQw" name="00N2C000000blQw" title="Title 2">
                        <option value="">--None--</option><?php
                        $i = 0;
                        for($i=0; $i<=100; $i+=5){
                            ?><option value="<?php print($i); ?>"><?php print($i)?>%</option><?php
                        }
                    ?></select>
                    <div class="error-inner">This field is required.</div>
                </span>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>    
</table>
```

Comment: I think you must hide the contents, instead of removing them. This would improve the load time !

Comment: You want to remove Rows , RIght ?

Comment: @Tushar even after hiding the whole table I am getting the values of the hidden text after submitting the form so I found it of no use.

Comment: @ShashiShekharKumar Please disable all your input tags (which you want to hide) first and then hide. This will prevent the hidden items from being posted

Comment: Simple. Just wrap your `table` in a `form` and use the form's id to reset it -- `document.getElementById('Form-ID').reset();`. No jQuery required at all.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Jquery

```
$(function(){
   $(".radioClass").on('change',function(){
       var value=$(this).val();
      if(value=="No")
       {  
           var table=$('#tableId').find('tr');
           $.each(table,function(i,data){
             var inputs=$(this).find('input').val("");
             var select= $(this).find('select').val("");
           });  
       }
       else
       {
           // Load rows
       }
   });
});
```

Comment: Sir, I don't want to remove the tr. I just want to empty the values stored in the input and select options. Can we do that.

Comment: Yes u can Do that too

Comment: wait Ill Edit the answer

Comment: Try This it will remove input and select fields values

Comment: Could you please show me in your above code, how can I just empty the Input type text. Change in the same code.